# login with outlook successfully but Redirect Url not working after login successfully - react native

Tags: android, ios, react-native

am working on react native app and using react-native-app-auth library login with outlook,
when i run app on ios device then redirect url working fine.
but when i run app on android device then then login successfully but redirect url not working.
my redirectUrl is : 'urn:ietf:wg:oauth:2.0:oob',
i try this but not work.

```
manifestPlaceholders = [`enter code here`
appAuthRedirectScheme: 'com.googleusercontent.apps.urn:ietf:wg:oauth:2.0:oob'
]
```

Answer (score 0):

Faced the same issue. Post some reading, came across this . https://github.com/openid/AppAuth-iOS/issues/194 which redirects us to [RFC 8252 Section 7.1](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc8252#section-7.1).

Please change it to a domain under your control as advised. Worked for me!